# Invalid object name error in DbContext subclass

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I'm building an mvc application and using code first. But when I'm try access the table, the mvc throw this error:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.Membro'.
```

My Context is:

```
public class JethroContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BaseIgreja> BaseIgrejas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Igreja> Igrejas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Celula> Celulas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Membro> Membros { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Distrito> Distritos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Setor> Setores { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ministerio> Ministerios { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

Searching on Google I found the solution, but not worked for me.

```
Database.SetInitializer<JethroContext>(null);
```

**EDIT I:**

Membro class

```
Public class Membro
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime DateCreate {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Does the table exist in your database?

Comment: Yes, there is a class "Membro", so it was instantiated in DbSet.

Comment: Just throwing this out:  Have you checked the permissions on the table?  I had a similar error and it was caused by the account that I was using did not have permissions to access the table.

Comment: But i'm use only code first, not have database. All my tables are like the EDIT I.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid object name 'dbo...'.

I just realised I had the wrong Catalog selected in my Connection string. Master Blunder!!!